# PHP Webhost Operation Checking

Tags: php, android, react-native, error-handling, web-hosting

I wanted perform checking if the PHP Webhost is complete whenever perform a update function, if everything doing fine then send an notification and let the Application know the Operation is Doing fine.

Basically I wanted to know if the query in PHP work and use my application to notify the user.

is there any way or method to do so?

I using this method to fetch data from PHP in my React Native App

```
RecipeUpdation = () =>{
   const { ID }  = this.state ;
   const { Name }  = this.state ;
   const { Type }  = this.state ;
   const { Ingredient }  = this.state ;
   const { Step } = this.state ;

   return fetch('https://www.update.php', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({

         RecipeID : ID,
       RecipeName : Name,
       RecipeType : Type,
       RecipeIngredient: Ingredient,
       RecipeStep: Step

       })

     }).then((response) => response.json())
           .then((responseJson) => {
           }).catch((error) => {
             console.error(error);
           });

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically we can verify if the Operation in PHP is successful or not by Checking the Query Execution Status. A very Basic way to do the checking is using `If Else` to see if the Query Function return `True`(Success) or `False`(Fail). You can also always return some Message through `JsonResponds`.

Here some example Code for PHP checking and Return Some Message:

```
// Using If Else to Check if operation Success or Not
if(mysqli_query($connection,$Your_Query)){

$MSG = 'Success' ;

// Convert message into Json format first
$json = json_encode($MSG);

// This is where it return the message to Application.
 echo $json ;

 }
 else{

 $MSG = 'Failed' ;

 $json = json_encode($MSG);

 echo $json ;
 }
```

In your Application Code you already have the implementation to retrieve the `JsonResponds`(the Message) which have been `echo` in the PHP Code, I would suggest use a simple method which is `Alert` to pop out the message in your React Native Application to notify the User the Operation Status.

```
 }).then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {

         // this responseJson Already have the echo Message from PHP
         // just Display the Status with Alert Function
         Alert.alert(responseJson);

       }).catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
```

Hope this would help.